# PERL : Unicode string : Permission denied

Tags: perl, module, permission-denied, unicode-string

I program using Perl and need to install Unicode String. But `make install` tells me:

> Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into
>   architecture dependent library tree
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   ERROR: Can't create
>   '/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Unicode' mkdir
>   /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Unicode: Permission
>   denied at /System/Library/Perl/5.16/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 494.
>
> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   at -e line 1. make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 13

Does anyone ever encountered this problem?

Comment: It seems pretty clear that the user running the `make` does not have permission to create a directory in that place. Change user? Or `sudo`.

Comment: You need permission to install into `/Library/`. Try with `sudo make install`, or change the installation prefix.

Comment: Thx, I tried sudo make install, it says "sudo make install Unicode::string
Password:
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop". What do you mean by "change the installation prefix?"

Comment: The recommendation to use `sudo` maybe well-intentioned, but it is **harmful**. Do not mess with OS X system Perl. Instead, install your own Perl in a user directory, I use `$HOME/perl/5.xx.x`, and use that. See http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/02/choose-the-right-perl-distribution/ if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

`/Library` is a system directory. It is a **bad** idea to tinker with your system's own Perl distribution. If anything goes wrong, you'll have a lot of cleanup to do.

Therefore, build your own Perl. All you need is to download the appropriate source distribution, and run `./Configure --help`, and read the instructions.

Or, you could just do:

```
$ ./Configure -des -Dprefix=/Users/user/perl/5.xx.x
make
make test
make install
```

You can then put `/Users/user/perl/5.xx.x/bin` on your path, or just invoke `perl` with the full path.

```
 $ ~/perl/5.xx.x/bin/perl Makefile.PL
make test
make install
```

I like to put symlinks in `~/bin` so that `perl5.xx.x` invokes `~/perl/5.xx.x/bin/perl`.

Do not install modules in system directories. I am sure people who recommended that mean well, but doing so is going to cause trouble at some point.

Comment: Or better, simply use [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am not in favor of anyone jumping into using `perlbrew` without understanding what it does behind the scenes. And, as much as I wanted to like it, all three times I tried to use it consistently, I ended up wiping `~/perl5` after a while. It doesn't do anything for me. So, better and simply are in the eyes of the beholder.

Comment: Thx everyone for you response! The problem was it didn't find the module for my currently activeperl (20), i re-downloaded activeperl 18, and re-installed unicode::string using the command /usr/local/ActivePerl-5.18/bin/ppm install Unicode-String, and now it works fine.